# How are modules resolved in ConTeXt?

Tags: context, modules

In [Document Titles](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Document_Titles) it says:

> Suppose that we save this in the file t-title.tex.

But in then it is mentioned:

> Then, we can use this in our main ConTeXt document with the following syntax, which is quite similar to the LaTeX version aside from the addition of the \usemodule[title] command in place of \documentclass{article}.

I am trying to understand why `t-` is prepended into the file name while `\usemodule[title]` omits this.

Say if I want to organise my reusable modules in a directory structure how do I use them?

Answer (score 9):

The module naming scheme is an unenforced contract.  You can acutally name your module anything of `m-title.tex`, `p-title.tex`, `x-title.tex`, `s-title.tex`, `t-title.tex`, `title.tex` as all these names will be tried (in that order I think).  Generally you should use either `t-title.tex` or `title.tex` since the other prefixes are reserved for internal use.  Other extensions than `.tex` are also possible, usually `.mkii` is chosen for MkII modules, `.mkiv` for MkIV modules and `.mkxl` for LMTX modules.  See the [Garden page on modules](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Modules#Usage) and [`file-mod.lua`](https://github.com/contextgarden/context-mirror/blob/03f6d43b4a5036b4cbb7e4df56db7217717bdadd/tex/context/base/mkiv/file-mod.lua#L37-L67) for details.

ConTeXt will look in `TEXMF` for these files which is defined in [`contextcnf.lua`](https://github.com/contextgarden/context-mirror/blob/beta/web2c/contextcnf.lua).  This includes the current working directory and its parent directory.